# Getting JQuery.inArray() to work

Tags: jquery, arrays

I'm using `inArray` to check if an option chosen from a  control exists in one of several arrays (and I'm then using that to customise and display some text).

My code is at http://codepen.io/marklsanders/pen/rWGgPE

I'm using a series of `if()` and `else if(0)` to check the existence of the chosen value against the arrays via inArray(), comparing the result to `-1`.

```
else if (jQuery.inArray(course, set_2) != -1) {text = text_2;}
```

In every case the code is falling through to the final `else` - *value not found.*

I'm sure there's a stupid error in there somewhere, but I can't see it.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

`course` needs to be a number. Remember that whatever text is in an input element is a string, even if the text is 1,2,3,etc.... So if you need a number from an input, convert the data to a number by using `Number(data)`, `parseInt(data, 10)`, or `parseFloat(data)`. Also, if your input is `type="number"` it still will be a string until it is converted into a number.

> `var course = Number($('#choose-a-course').val());`

<kbd>[CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/zer00ne/pen/jVGgwM?editors=0010)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

yaa your course number is a string,convert it to a number

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var set_1 = [2, 3, 4, 7, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 29, 30, 31, 36, 37, 38, 39, 43, 44, 45, 55, 58, 59, 61, 62, 63, 64, 67, 68, 69, 76, 77, 79, 85, 86, 90, 91, 92, 93, 95, 96, 97, 100, 112, 113, 116, 117, 118, 119, 122, 133, 139, 147, 148, 149];
  var set_2 = [46, 48, 49, 50, 70, 81, 128, 129, 130, 131, 132, 136, 137, 138, 141, 142, 143];
  var set_3 = [1, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 66, 80, 83, 84, 94];
  var set_4 = [8, 9, 10];
  var set_5 = [41, 42, 134, 135];
  var set_6 = [5, 6, 33, 34, 54, 60, 74, 75, 87, 88, 89, 99, 123, 144];
  var set_7 = [35, 56, 57, 124];
  var set_8 = [65, 101, 102, 107, 108, 109];
  var set_9 = [20, 21, 32, 40, 51, 52, 53, 71, 72, 73, 78, 82, 98, 103, 104, 105, 106, 111, 114, 115, 120, 121, 125, 126, 127, 140, 145, 146];
  //console.log ("hello");
  var text = "";
  var heading = "<h2>Applicant Visit Days</h2><p>Applicant Visit Days are available for the course you chose on the following dates:</p>";
  $('.hide-me').hide();
  text_1 = '<ul><li>8 Feb</li><li>25 Feb</li><li>22 April</li></ul>';
  text_2 = '<ul><li>15 Feb</li><li>22 March</li><li>22 April</li></ul>';
  text_3 = '<ul><li>22 Feb</li><li>25 Feb</li><li>22 April</li></ul>';
  text_4 = '<ul><li>8 Feb</li><li>25 Feb</li></ul>';
  text_5 = '<ul><li>22 Feb</li><li>22 April</li></ul>';
  text_6 = '<ul><li>15 March/li><li>22 April</li></ul>';
  text_7 = '<ul><li>25 Feb</li><li>15 March</li><li>22 April</li></ul>';
  text_8 = '<ul><li>22 March</li><li>22 April</li></ul>';
  text_9 = '<ul><li>22 April</li></ul>';
  $('#choose-a-course').change(function() {
    //console.log("changed");
    var course = parseInt($('#choose-a-course').val(), 10);


    console.log("Value changed to " + course);
    if (jQuery.inArray(course, set_1) != -1) {
      alert(text);
      text = text_1;
    } else if (jQuery.inArray(course, set_2) != -1) {
      text = text_2;
    } else if (jQuery.inArray(course, set_3) != -1) {
      text = text_2;
    } else if (jQuery.inArray(course, set_4) != -1) {
      text = text_2;
    } else if (jQuery.inArray(course, set_5) != -1) {
      text = text_2;
    } else if (jQuery.inArray(course, set_6) != -1) {
      text = text_2;
    } else if (jQuery.inArray(course, set_7) != -1) {
      text = text_2;
    } else if (jQuery.inArray(course, set_8) != -1) {
      text = text_2;
    } else if (jQuery.inArray(course, set_9) != -1) {
      text = text_2;
    } else {

      text = "couldn't match the value";
    }
    //console.log (text);
    $('.hide-me').html(heading + text);
    $('.hide-me').show("slow");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-12">
  <h2>Choose a course</h2>
  <select id="choose-a-course">
    <option selected disabled>Choose a course:</option>
    <option value="1">Accounting and Finance (BSc)</option>
    <option value="2">Aeronautical Engineering (BEng/MEng)</option>
    <option value="3">Aeronautical Engineering with Foundation Year (BEng)</option>
    <option value="4">Aircraft Engineering with Pilot Studies (BEng/MEng)</option>
    <option value="5">Animation (BA)</option>
    <option value="6">Animation with Industry Placement (BA)</option>
    <option value="7">Archaeology and Geography with Professional Practice (BSc)</option>
    <option value="8">Architectural Design and Technology (Accelerated Degree) (BSc)</option>
    <option value="9">Architectural Design and Technology (BSc)</option>
    <option value="10">Architecture (BSc)</option>
    <option value="11">Audio Acoustics (BEng)</option>
    <option value="12">Audio Acoustics with Foundation Year (BEng)</option>
    <option value="13">Aviation Technology with Pilot Studies (BSc)</option>
    <option value="14">Biochemistry (BSc)</option>
    <option value="15">Biochemistry with Studies in USA (BSc)</option>
    <option value="16">Biology (BSc)</option>
    <option value="17">Biology Foundation Year</option>
    <option value="18">Biology with Studies in USA (BSc)</option>
    <option value="19">Biomedical Science (BSc)</option>
    <option value="20">Building Surveying (Accelerated Degree) (BSc)</option>
    <option value="21">Building Surveying (BSc)</option>
    <option value="22">Business and Economics (BSc)</option>
    <option value="23">Business and Financial Management (BSc)</option>
    <option value="24">Business and Management (BSc)</option>
    <option value="25">Business and Tourism Management (BSc)</option>
    <option value="26">Business Information Technology (BSc)</option>
    <option value="27">Business Management with Law (BSc)</option>
    <option value="28">Business Management with Sport (BSc)</option>
    <option value="29">Civil and Architectural Engineering (BEng/MEng)</option>
    <option value="30">Civil Engineering (BSc/BEng/MEng)</option>
    <option value="31">Civil Engineering with Foundation Year (BEng)</option>
    <option value="32">Comedy Writing and Performance (BA)</option>
    <option value="33">Computer and Video Games (BSc)</option>
    <option value="34">Computer and Video Games with Industy Placement (BSc)</option>
    <option value="35">Computer Networks (BSc)</option>
    <option value="36">Computer Science (BSc)</option>
    <option value="37">Computer Science and Web Development(BSc)</option>
    <option value="38">Computer Science with Cyber Security (BSc)</option>
    <option value="39">Computer Science with Data Analytics (BSc)</option>
    <option value="40">Construction (HNC)</option>
    <option value="41">Construction Project Management (Accelerated Degree) (BSc)</option>
    <option value="42">Construction Project Management (BSc)</option>
    <option value="43">Contemporary History and Politics (BA)</option>
    <option value="44">Contemporary Military and International History (BA)</option>
    <option value="45">Corporate Law (LLB)</option>
    <option value="46">Counselling and Psychotherapy: Professional Practice (BSc)</option>
    <option value="47">Course title</option>
    <option value="48">Criminology (BSc)</option>
    <option value="49">Criminology and Sociology (BSc)</option>
    <option value="50">Criminology with Counselling (BSc)</option>
    <option value="51">Dance (BA)</option>
    <option value="52">Design (BA)</option>
    <option value="53">Diagnostic Radiography (BSc)</option>
    <option value="54">Digital Media (BA)</option>
    <option value="55">Drama and Creative Writing (BA)</option>
    <option value="56">Electronic Engineering (BEng)</option>
    <option value="57">Electronic Engineering with Foundation Year(BEng)</option>
    <option value="58">English and Creative Writing (BA)</option>
    <option value="59">English and Drama (BA)</option>
    <option value="60">English and Film (BA)</option>
    <option value="61">English Language (BA)</option>
    <option value="62">English Language and Creative Writing (BA)</option>
    <option value="63">English Literature (BA)</option>
    <option value="64">English Literature with English Language (BA)</option>
    <option value="65">Enhancing Professional Health Care Practice (BSc)</option>
    <option value="66">Enterprise, Leadership and Management (BSc)</option>
    <option value="67">Environmental Health (BSc)</option>
    <option value="68">Environmental Management (BSc)</option>
    <option value="69">Environmental Management Foundation Year</option>
    <option value="70">Exercise, Physical Activity and Health (BSc)</option>
    <option value="71">Fashion Design (BA)</option>
    <option value="72">Fashion Image Making and Styling (BA)</option>
    <option value="73">Film and TV Set Design (BA)</option>
    <option value="74">Film Production (BA)</option>
    <option value="75">Film Studies (BA)</option>
    <option value="76">Financial Mathematics BSc (Hons)</option>
    <option value="77">Geography (BA/BSc)</option>
    <option value="78">Graphic Design (BA)</option>
    <option value="79">Human Biology and Infectious Diseases (BSc)</option>
    <option value="80">Human Resource Management (BSc)</option>
    <option value="81">Integrated Practice in Learning Disabilities Nursing and Social Work (BSc)</option>
    <option value="82">Interior Design (BA)</option>
    <option value="83">International Business (BSc)</option>
    <option value="84">International Events Management (BSc)</option>
    <option value="85">International Politics and Security (BA)</option>
    <option value="86">International Relations and Politics (BA)</option>
    <option value="87">Journalism (Broadcast) (BA)</option>
    <option value="88">Journalism (Multimedia) (BA)</option>
    <option value="89">Journalism and English (BA)</option>
    <option value="90">Law (LLB)</option>
    <option value="91">Law (Media and Digital Industries) (LLB)</option>
    <option value="92">Law with Criminology (LLB)</option>
    <option value="93">Law with Management (LLB)</option>
    <option value="94">Marketing (BSc)</option>
    <option value="95">Mathematics (BSc)</option>
    <option value="96">Mechanical Engineering (BEng/MEng)</option>
    <option value="97">Mechanical Engineering with Foundation Year (BEng)</option>
    <option value="98">Media and Performance (BA)</option>
    <option value="99">Media Technology (BSc)</option>
    <option value="100">Medicinal Chemistry (BSc)</option>
    <option value="101">Midwifery - 156 weeks (BSc)</option>
    <option value="102">Midwifery - Post RN (BSc)</option>
    <option value="103">Music Foundation Year (all pathways)</option>
    <option value="104">Music: Creative Music Technology (BA)</option>
    <option value="105">Music: Musical Arts (BA)</option>
    <option value="106">Music: Popular Music and Recording (BA)</option>
    <option value="107">Nursing (Adult) (BSc)</option>
    <option value="108">Nursing (Children and Young People) (BSc)</option>
    <option value="109">Nursing (Mental Health) (BSc)</option>
    <option value="110">Nursing Theory (one year top up) (BSc)</option>
    <option value="111">Occupational Therapy (BSc)</option>
    <option value="112">Petroleum and Mechanical Engineering (BEng)</option>
    <option value="113">Pharmaceutical Science (BSc)</option>
    <option value="114">Photography (BA)</option>
    <option value="115">Photography with Industry Placement (BA)</option>
    <option value="116">Physics (BSc/MPhys)</option>
    <option value="117">Physics with Acoustics (BSc/MPhys)</option>
    <option value="118">Physics with Foundation Year (BSc)</option>
    <option value="119">Physics with Studies in North America (MPhys)</option>
    <option value="120">Physiotherapy (BSc)</option>
    <option value="121">Podiatry (BSc)</option>
    <option value="122">Politics (BA)</option>
    <option value="123">Professional Broadcast Techniques (BSc)</option>
    <option value="124">Professional Sound and Video Technology (BSc)</option>
    <option value="125">Property and Real Estate (Accelerated Degree) (BSc)</option>
    <option value="126">Property and Real Estate (BSc)</option>
    <option value="127">Prosthetics and Orthotics (BSc)</option>
    <option value="128">Psychology (BSc)</option>
    <option value="129">Psychology and Counselling (BSc)</option>
    <option value="130">Psychology and Criminology (BSc)</option>
    <option value="131">Psychology of Sport (BSc)</option>
    <option value="132">Public Health (BSc)</option>
    <option value="133">Pure and Applied Physics (BSc)</option>
    <option value="134">Quantity Surveying (Accelerated Degree) (BSc)</option>
    <option value="135">Quantity Surveying (BSc)</option>
    <option value="136">Social Policy (BSc)</option>
    <option value="137">Social Work (BA)</option>
    <option value="138">Sociology (BSc)</option>
    <option value="139">Software Engineering (BSc)</option>
    <option value="140">Sport Rehabilitation (BSc)</option>
    <option value="141">Sports Science (Human Performance pathway) (BSc)</option>
    <option value="142">Sports Science (Performance Analysis) (BSc)</option>
    <option value="143">Sports Science (Strength and Conditioning pathway) (BSc)</option>
    <option value="144">Television and Radio (BA)</option>
    <option value="145">Theatre and Performance Practice (BA)</option>
    <option value="146">Visual Arts (BA)</option>
    <option value="147">Wildlife and Practical Conservation (BSc)</option>
    <option value="148">Wildlife Conservation with Zoo Biology (BSc)</option>
    <option value="149">Zoology (BSc)</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div class="col-md-12 hide-me">
</div>
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Let us know what helped you

Answer (score 0):

**course** variable must have the same data type of array items. Convert your `course` variable to number.

Change

> ```
>  var course = $('#choose-a-course').val();
> ```

To this

> ```
> var course = Number($('#choose-a-course').val());
> ```

<kbd>[See in Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zoEgdp)</kbd>